# H2DB インメモリで DDL(sqlファイル)からテーブルを作成できません

Tags: maven, junit

Mavenのweb-appプロジェクトを作成し、H2DB インメモリモードでDB周りのテストコードを書いています。

```
org.h2.tools.RunScript.execute（）；
```

を使ってsqlファイルを読み込んでテーブル作成したいのですが、
作成できていないようで、`'NoSuchTableException'` が出ます。

もし、原因になりそうな情報があれば、お教え願えますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

自作のメソッドでエラーが出ている行番号です。↓

```
    at testModel.LoginLogicTest.readDataSet(LoginLogicTest.java:33)
    at testModel.LoginLogicTest.createSchema(LoginLogicTest.java:59)
```

LoginLogicTest.java

```
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = org.h2.Driver.class.getName();
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4";
    private static final String USER = "sa";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";
```

```
//(変更後)
    public static IDataSet readDataSet(String dataPath)throws Exception{

//(LoginLogicTest.java:33)

          IDataSet dataSet=new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File(dataPath));

          return dataSet;
      }
    public static void cleanlyInsert(IDataSet dataSet)throws Exception{

          IDatabaseTester dbTester=new JdbcDatabaseTester(JDBC_DRIVER,JDBC_URL,USER,PASSWORD);
          dbTester.setSetUpOperation(DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT);
          dbTester.setDataSet(dataSet);
          dbTester.onSetup();
      }

      public static DataSource dataSource() {
          JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
          dataSource.setURL(JDBC_URL);
          dataSource.setUser(USER);
          dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
          return dataSource;
      }
      @BeforeAll
      public static void createSchema() throws Exception {
        RunScript.execute(JDBC_URL, USER, PASSWORD, "src/test/resources/schema.sql", null , false);

//(LoginLogicTest.java:59)

        IDataSet dataset=readDataSet("src/test/resources/setup_dataset.xml");
        cleanlyInsert(dataset);
      }
  :
  :
```

スタックトレース

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: Account
    at org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractDataSet.getTable(AbstractDataSet.java:172)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatDtdDataSet.getTable(FlatDtdDataSet.java:181)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractDataSet.getTableMetaData(AbstractDataSet.java:156)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatDtdDataSet.getTableMetaData(FlatDtdDataSet.java:168)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlProducer.createTableMetaData(FlatXmlProducer.java:189)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlProducer.startElement(FlatXmlProducer.java:445)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlProducer.produce(FlatXmlProducer.java:365)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.CachedDataSet.<init>(CachedDataSet.java:80)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet.<init>(FlatXmlDataSet.java:110)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSetBuilder.buildInternal(FlatXmlDataSetBuilder.java:264)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSetBuilder.build(FlatXmlDataSetBuilder.java:111)   

 at testModel.LoginLogicTest.readDataSet(LoginLogicTest.java:33)    
 at testModel.LoginLogicTest.createSchema(LoginLogicTest.java:59)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at .....
 :
 :
```

追記
pom.xml(省略版、h2db関連のみ)
※その他schema.sqlはh2コンソールで動作確認済み。

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
:
:
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    :
  <dependencies>
    :
    :
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.199</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
     :
     :
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
         :  
         :
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.5</version>
           <configuration>
              <driver>org.h2.Driver</driver>
              <url>jdbc:h2:mem:test</url>
              <username>sa</username>
              <password> </password>
              <srcFiles>
                  <srcFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/schema.sql</srcFile>
              </srcFiles>
          </configuration>
      　</plugin>
    　</plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <finalName>upload_image_db2</finalName>
 </build>
</project>
```

/src/test/resources/setup_dataset.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<dataset>
  <Account userId="Shima5" pass="135790" name="Shima.I" age="33"/>
</dataset>
```

Comment: [同様のコード](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so57030)を実行してみましたが、問題なく動作しているようです。例外スタックトレースを全て載せられますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
確認のため、メソッドを切り離す変更をしたので、エラーの行番が変わってしまいました。長くなりますが、変更箇所とスタックトレースを追記させて頂きます。
何れにしても、
`IDataSet dataSet=new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File(dataPath));`
の部分で、引っかかってしまいます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setup_dataset.xml` で DTD を指定していると思いますが、`setup_dataset.xml`で操作しようとしているテーブル(名) `Account` が、そのDTDで定義されていないため該当の例外が出ていると考えられます。

この類いの問題については、検証機能がついたXMLエディタ(例えば私はEclipse IDEに組み込まれているものを用いました)で編集すると事前に検出が可能でしょう。

(また一応、DBUnitとしてはDTD指定が無くとも動作するので、`setup_dataset.xml`から`DOCTYPE`を削除してしまう、というのも回避策としては考えられます。`setup_dataset.xml`の記述が正であるならば。)

Comment: [再現コード](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/d4b5e7060ceb6f1b76a92f50df0890c8d90a34a8/so57030)。例えば[`member`](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/blob/d4b5e7060ceb6f1b76a92f50df0890c8d90a34a8/so57030/src/test/resources/setup_dataset.xml#L5-L6)を別の名前に変えると質問文中の例外が発生します。

Comment: コードまで添付して頂き、有難うございます。
.dtdは元々、勉強のために使ってみただけなので、仰る様に一度DOCTYPEを削除、関係のコードを除去してみました。しかしながら依然`table not found`が出ます。tableができないのは、h2のmemで接続できていないのでしょうか？もしかしたら、pomの設定に問題があるのかと思い追記しました。何か疑われることがあればコメントいただけると幸いです。

Comment: `setup_dataset.xml`から [`<!DOCTYPE configuration>` 行を除去してみてください](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/commit/a8f464b330e3a01a04d55ff0b7b418d573bb4b39)。

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。
有難うございます。実は当初、除いた状態からやっていて、
何かのエラーがきっかけで調べて`setContentType`をつけたのですが、
`「文書に対する文法制約 (DTD または XML スキーマ) の参照がありません。」
`という警告が出るので、`<!DOCTYPE>`をつけていました。
今回、どうも`IDatabaseTester`のメソッドの順番に問題があった様で、
始めそれを直しても状況が変わらなかったのですが、仰る様に`<!DOCTYPE>`の行ごと消したら先に進むことができました。ご丁寧に回答いただき感謝しております。